# Redirection with .htaccess maintaining the subdomain url instead of the path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, masking

I made a subdomain `site.domain.com.co` and has its files at `domain.com.co/site`, and it redirects fine with this htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.domain\.com\.co$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site\.domain\.com\.co$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/domain\.com\.co\/site\/" [R=301,L]
```

But it still showing the path `domain.com.co/site` in the url, and i need it to show the subdomain i created `site.domain.com.co`.

A couple of weeks ago, the owner of this domain applied a security certificate (https) to the domain and he says the subdomain was displaying correctly (not the path) before the certificate was aplied (i'm not sure if it's true).

Thanks!

EDITED

I founded the answer. Here's the full code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.domain\.com\.co$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site\.domain\.com\.co$
RewriteRule ^site\.domain\.com\.co?$ "https\:\/\/domain\.com\.co\/site\/" [R=301,L]
```